# virtual function vs. function pointer - performance?

Tags: c++, c

Are C++ virtual functions called on a polymorphic base class just as fast as calling a C-style function pointer? Is there really any difference?

I'm considering refactoring some performance-minded code that utilizes function pointers and change them over to virtual functions in polymorphism.

Comment: In c++ use std::function and test your code before you decide you need to make it faster, virtual functions are not that slow!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: How do you think polymorphic method calls are implemented? A very common method uses function pointers...

Comment: @dmckee: Actually, considering how polymorphic method calls are implemented, I'd imagine function pointers to be _faster_ (no vtable lookup)

Comment: If a significant fraction of your memory is taken by those function pointers, the vtable implementation could improve performance by reducing memory footprint and increasing cache locality.

Comment: In cases where the dynamic type is statically known, the compiler can de-virtualize function calls. The same is probably out of the optimizer's reach with a table of function pointers.

Comment: @Casey Constant propagation can turn an indirect branch to a direct one. In fact, there is no syntactic difference between a constant function reference (the name of the function) and one whose referent is unknown. That said, indirect branches cannot usually be eliminated because we don't usually use them unless needed (Java-style code with everything gratuitously `virtual` notwithstanding.)

Comment: It might be worthwhile to consider redesigning the code to avoid either of those mechanisms... instead maybe use templates so that your polymorphism decisions are made at compile-time rather than at run time.  (Whether or not this is possible would depend on what the program is trying to do, of course)

Comment: In addition to @jeremyfriesners remark I like to ask what the reason for refactoring is? Your current solution is certainly memory efficient, moving to a class based approach also adds bookkeeping complexity and overhead. The runtime performance penalty of the calls themselves is neglectible.

Comment: It probably won't actually matter in most real life situations..

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'd say most of the C++ implementations work similar to this (and probably the first
implementations, that compiled into C, produced code like this):

```
struct ClassVTABLE {
    void (* virtuamethod1)(Class *this);
    void (* virtuamethod2)(Class *this, int arg);
};

struct Class {
    ClassVTABLE *vtable;
};
```

Then, given an instance `Class x`, calling the method `virtualmethod1` for it is like `x.vtable->virtualmethod1(&x)`, thus one extra dereference, 1 indexed lookup from the `vtable`, and one extra argument (= `this`) pushed onto the stack / passed in registers.

However the compiler probably can optimize repeated method calls on an instance within a function: since an instance `Class x` cannot change its class after it is constructed, the compiler can consider the whole `x.vtable->virtualmethod1` as a common sub-expression, and move it out of loops. Thus in this case the repeated virtual method calls within a single function would be equivalent in speed to calling a function via a simple function pointer.

Answer (score 22):

> Are C++ virtual functions called on a polymorphic base class just as
>   fast as calling a C-style function pointer? Is there really any
>   difference?

Apples and oranges. At a miniscule "one vs. one" kind of level, a virtual function call involves slightly more work as there's an indirection/indexing overhead to get from `vptr` to `vtable` entry.

**But a Virtual Function Call Can Be Faster**

Okay, how could this be? I just said a virtual function call requires slightly more work, which is true.

What people tend to forget is to try to make a closer comparison here (to try to make it a little less apples and oranges, even though it is apples and oranges). We typically don't create a class with just one virtual function in it. If we did, then performance (as well as even things like code size) would definitely favor a function pointer. We often have something more like this:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    virtual ~Foo() {}
    virtual f1() = 0;
    virtual f2() = 0;
    virtual f3() = 0;
    virtual f4() = 0;
};
```

... in which case a more "direct" function pointer analogy might be this:

```
struct Bar
{
     void (*f1)();
     void (*f2)();
     void (*f3)();
     void (*f4)();
};
```

In this kind of case, calling virtual functions in each instance of `Foo` can be considerably more efficient than `Bar`. It's due to the fact that `Foo` only needs to store a single vptr to a central vtable which is being accessed repeatedly. With that we get improved locality of reference (smaller `Foos` and ones that can potentially fit better and in number into a cache line, more frequent access of `Foo's` central vtable).

`Bar`, on the other hand, requires more memory and is effectively duplicating the contents of `Foo's` vtable in each instance of `Bar` (let's say there are a million instances of `Foo` and `Bar`). In that case, the amount of redundant data inflating the size of `Bar` will often significantly outweigh the cost of doing slightly less work per function pointer call.

If we only need to store one function pointer per object, and this was an extreme hot spot, then it might be good to just store a function pointer (ex: it might be useful for someone implementing anything remotely resembling `std::function` to just store a function pointer).

So it's kind of apples and oranges, but if we're modeling a use case anything close to this, the vtable kind of approach which stores a central, shared table of function addresses (in C or C++) can be considerably more efficient.

If we're modeling a use case where we just have one single function pointer stored in an object vs. a vtable which has only one virtual function in it, then the function pointer would be slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 8):

It is UNLIKELY you'll see much of a difference, but like all these things, it's often the small details (such as the compiler needing to pass a `this` pointer to a virtual function) that can cause differences in performance. The `virtual` function itself is a function pointer "under the hood", so you probably get pretty similar code in both cases, once the compiler has done its thing.

It sounds like a good use of virtual functions, and if someone objected and said "there will be a performance difference", I'd say "prove it". But if you want to avoid having that discussion, make a benchmark (if there isn't one already) that measures the performance of the existing code, refactor it (or some part of it) and compare the results. Ideally, test on a couple of different machines, so that you don't get results that work better on YOUR machine, but not so good on some other types of machines (different generations of processors, different manufacturer or processor, etc).

Comment: Fantastic. The function pointers are already passing the object, so I figured virtual functions were probably the same thing. Been reading other virtual function posts on SO about performance so I wanted to be sure there wasn't something else that C++ did other than abstract that for you.

Answer (score 8):

A virtual function call involves two dereferences, one of them indexed, i.e. something like `*(object->_vtable[3])()`.

A call via a function pointer involves one dereference.

A method call also requires passing a hidden argument to be received as `this`.

Unless the method body is practically empty and there are no arguments or return values you are most unlikely to notice the difference.

Comment: I'm not sure this treatment is quite fair. The corresponding construct in C would be to dereference a pointer to a struct to get the function pointer (which you then dereference). There are two dereferences here in C. Now I know that a plain function pointer is one dereference, but the use case for a virtual function requires an object to own the function, so I think it's only fair the C version requires it as well. Also worth noting that under special circumstances, the compiler can optimize the virtual call away without the programmer explicitly doing so (as C would require it).

Comment: A virtual call requires fetching the vtable pointer from the object, fetching the function pointer from the vtable, and performing an indirect jump. The function pointer requires fetching the function pointer from somewhere, and performing an indirect jump. The relative speeds depend on what's in the cache, but the jump is usually the slow part.

Comment: @ThomasEding No, the vtable base is contained in the object and needs to be fetched, although it might already be "hot".

Comment: @ThomasEding You are guesssing about how the OP's code is written. I am answering the question that was actually asked.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between a function pointer call and a virtual function call is negligible unless you already measured that the above is a bottleneck.

The only difference is:

- a virtual function has a memory read for the vtable, and the indirect call to the address of the function
- a function pointer has just one indirect call to the function

This because the virtual function requires to lookup the address of the function it is going to call while the function pointer already knows it (since it's stored in itself).

I would add that, since you are working with C++, **virtual methods** should be the way to go.

Comment: -1, what do you mean by an "indirect call" for the vtable? There is at most one indirect jump instruction needed for any virtual dispatch implementation.

Comment: There is an indirect read to fetch the `vtable`. However, this can quite often be optimised away.

Comment: Yeah, but that's by no means a "call." Indirect calls often flush the pipeline.

Comment: Since you are working with C++, you have both function pointers AND virtual methods to work with. Throw in functors and std::functions for good measure too, and maybe CRTP. None of them are "the way to go" -- that depends on what you're doing.

Comment: @Cory Nelson: Actually I don't the benefit of using a function pointer instead that a virtual function (or `std::function`) unless working with mixed C code.

Comment: All calls will force the processor to fetch new instructions (flush the pipeline). Modern processors can often predict even indirect calls - but not always - particularly not if a set of objects being operated on are all jumping to different places - but of course, that is the same problem if you are using function pointers or virtual methods.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I don't know how you figure 'at most one'. You have to fetch the address of the vtable from the object, index to the method slot, then fetch the function address from that slot. You can combine the last two into one instruction on most processors (e.g. x86 `LEA`).

Comment: @MatsPetersson That's not what "flush the pipeline" means. Function calls are usually not conditional, therefore they are predictable. Indirect calls can be predicted if they are predictable, which they are usually not. (Otherwise you wouldn't be using them.)

Comment: @EJP a "call" and a "fetch" are completely different things. If they even sound similar to you, you aren't qualified to answer this question.

Comment: @Potatoswatter As I didn't say anything about calls, your comment lacks relevance. I am quoting your statement above about 'at most one indirect jump instruction'. I advise you not to indulge yourself in further speculations about my qualifications here.

Comment: @EJP Is a jump like a call, or is a jump like a fetch? (A call is a jump plus an adjustment to the stack. A function call may be implemented as a pure jump if it is a tail call, so the distinction is not significant here.)

Comment: @Jack It isn't clear if OP is replacing all of a virtual function's functionality with a function pointer, or if he just has an opportunity to (perhaps mis)use a C++ feature.

I'll give you that if he's asking this question his idea of "performance-minded code" might not hold the same meaning as it does to someone more experienced, but I've ran into at least one situation (single virtual call + heavy multiple inheritance + CRTP) where replacing a virtual function with a function pointer had significant positive effects.

Answer (score 1):

[Speed test results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEXCS.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define CALCULATING return 1;
//#define CALCULATING int res = 0;\
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)\
                        res += i;\
                    return res;

static int Deriver1_foo_pf_impl()
{
    CALCULATING
}

int f_foo()
{
    CALCULATING
}

inline int if_foo()
{
    CALCULATING
}

class MyClass
{
public:
    int foo()
    {
        CALCULATING
    }
};

class IBase
{
public:
    virtual int foo()
    {
        CALCULATING
    }
};

class Deriver1 : public IBase
{
public:
    int foo() override
    {
        CALCULATING
    }
};

class Deriver2 : public Deriver1
{
public:
    int foo() override
    {
        CALCULATING
    }
};

class IBase_pf
{
public:
    int (*foo)();
};

class Deriver1_pf : public IBase_pf
{
protected:

public:
    Deriver1_pf()
    {
        this->foo = &f_foo;
    }
};

int main()
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    std::cout << "DEBUG VERSION" << std::endl << std::endl;
#else
    std::cout << "RELEASE VERSION" << std::endl << std::endl;
#endif // _DEBUG

    std::cout.precision(10);

    unsigned long long countOfCalls = 1000000000;
    unsigned long long trash = 0;

    int (*pf_variable)() = &f_foo;

    Deriver2 vpt;
    Deriver1_pf fpo;
    MyClass mcf;

    clock_t start;
    clock_t end;

    std::cout << "Count of call funtions and methods : " << countOfCalls << std::endl << std::endl;

    start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < countOfCalls; i++)
    {
        trash += vpt.foo();
    }
    end = clock();
    
    std::cout << "Virtual method : " << std::endl << "\t";
    std::cout << "time : " << end - start << ", calling per second : " << static_cast<double>(countOfCalls) / (static_cast<double>(end - start)) / 1000 << "(millions per sec), trash : " << trash << std::endl;
    trash = 0;

    start = clock();

    for (int i = 0; i < countOfCalls; i++)
    {
        trash += fpo.foo();
    }
    end = clock();

    std::cout << "Function poiter from base overridden in deriver : " << std::endl << "\t";
    std::cout << "time : " << end - start << ", calling per second : " << static_cast<double>(countOfCalls) / (static_cast<double>(end - start)) / 1000 << "(millions per sec), trash : " << trash << std::endl;
    trash = 0;

    start = clock();

    for (int i = 0; i < countOfCalls; i++)
    {
        trash += mcf.foo();
    }
    end = clock();

    std::cout << "Classic method : " << std::endl << "\t";
    std::cout << "time : " << end - start << ", calling per second : " << static_cast<double>(countOfCalls) / (static_cast<double>(end - start)) / 1000 << "(millions per sec), trash : " << trash << std::endl;
    trash = 0;

    start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < countOfCalls; i++)
    {
        trash += pf_variable();
    }
    end = clock();

    std::cout << "Call classic c-style function by function pointer (Callback) : " << std::endl << "\t";
    std::cout << "time : " << end - start << ", calling per second : " << static_cast<double>(countOfCalls) / (static_cast<double>(end - start)) / 1000 << "(millions per sec), trash : " << trash << std::endl;
    trash = 0;

    start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < countOfCalls; i++)
    {
        trash += f_foo();
    }
    end = clock();

    std::cout << "Classic C-style function : " << std::endl << "\t";
    std::cout << "time : " << end - start << ", calling per second : " << static_cast<double>(countOfCalls) / (static_cast<double>(end - start)) / 1000 << "(millions per sec), trash : " << trash << std::endl;
    trash = 0;

    start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < countOfCalls; i++)
    {
        trash += if_foo();
    }
    end = clock();

    std::cout << "Inline classic C-style function : " << std::endl << "\t";
    std::cout << "time : " << end - start << ", calling per second : " << static_cast<double>(countOfCalls) / (static_cast<double>(end - start)) / 1000 << "(millions per sec), trash : " << trash << std::endl;
    trash = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

Virtual methods works faster than callbacks.
It can be result of optimizations for virtual methods or miss caches of callbacks or both

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).